# pragma busy_timeout not working

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to view and change the busy_timeout parameter in a SQLite database, but I can not view the output from `pragma busy_timeout`.

```
sqlite> PRAGMA busy_timeout = 1000;
sqlite> PRAGMA busy_timeout;
sqlite>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

SQLite version 3.7.10

```
sqlite> pragma compile_options;
ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_RTREE
TEMP_STORE=1
THREADSAFE=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRAGMA busy_timeout` was added in version [3.7.15](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_15.html).